# IBM Message Broker: Trace Nodes File Path Configurable

Tags: trace, messagebroker, configurable

I'm trying to make several trace nodes, each with a configurable file path.

I prefer if it were through a configurable service in the message broker, though is it possible? If not, are there other ways to make them configurable?

Answer (score 0):

Not on a per application / flow basis. If you just want to be able to set a common root then you can use relative paths.

It's not reccomended but you can use relative file paths in the trace node. By default this is relative to the broker's view of the current working directory.

This changes between v7 and v8 so if you really want to use relative  you can set the environment variable MQSI_TRACENODES_ROOT_DIRECTORY to hold the base path then set a relative path in your node names.

The other approach you could use is to override the property in the bar file prior to moving between your different environments.

For what its worth I think that having this configurable at runtime is a great idea so I would encourage you to raise a request for enhancement to bring it to the attention of the Broker dev team:

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rfe/?PROD_ID=532